# Dart - HttpRequest.getString() return JSON

Tags: json, api, server, dart

I am trying to return the raw JSON from my server path (I use rpc for the API) with a Closure, because I want to keep it in the same function instead of using .then() and calling another one.

This is my code:

```
GetEntryDiscussionsFromDb(){
  var url = "http://localhost:8082/discussionApi/v1/getAllDiscussions";

  getRawJson(String response){
    return response;
  }

  HttpRequest.getString(url).then(getRawJson);
  return getRawJson;
}
```

then in my main function I do this:

```
var getRawJson = GetEntryDiscussionsFromDb();
print(getRawJson());
```

By doing so I get this error:

```
G.GetEntryDiscussionsFromDb(...).call$0 is not a function
```

Did I use Closures wrong? Is there maybe a way to return the actual raw Json inside of .then() instead of calling another function?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you try to accomplish. What is `return getRawJson;` supposed to do?

`getRawJson` just returns a reference to the `getRawJson` method. When you use `getRawJson`

```
print(getRawJson());
```

calls `getRawJson` without a parameter, but it expects `String response`. This is why you get the error message.

You can't avoid using `then`. Alternatively you can use `async`/`await`

```
GetEntryDiscussionsFromDb(){
  var url = "http://localhost:8082/discussionApi/v1/getAllDiscussions";

  getRawJson(String response){
    return response;
  }

  return HttpRequest.getString(url).then(getRawJson);
}
```

main

```
GetEntryDiscussionsFromDb()
.then(print);
```

or

```
main() async {
  ...
  var json = await GetEntryDiscussionsFromDb();
  print(json);
}
```

Comment: Oh, didn't know I could use then whencalling my GetEntryDiscussionsFromDb from main... thank you :)

Comment: `then()` returns a `Future` and you can call `then` on that `Future` again.